# Not able to connect to serial in python

Tags: python, pyserial

I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'` I already have installed "pyserial" by running `"pip install pyserial"` in CMD.

Here is my simple code. I also see the COM port 8 is visible in the Device Manager.

```py
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial("COM8", 9600)
```

I get the error when I run the above commands.

Comment: What versions of python so you have installed? It sounds like you installed `pyserial` to one version, but you are using a different version to run your code.

Comment: do you installed some other module named `serial`? what is output of `pip list | grep serial`

Comment: I get this message on CMD 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ignore that comment. What versions of python do you have installed?

Comment: If I type "pip --version" then I get this on CMD "pip 21.1.3"

Comment: Ok, but which versions of `python` do you have installed? Have you got folders like: `C:\Python36`?